# how do you make a login system?

Tags: social-media

I was wondering if there was a way to make a login and sign up system for my website.

I have been all over the web trying to find a solution to my problem but unfortunately i have had no luck at all.

If anybody would mind helping me i would be very grateful as I am trying to build a social media site.

I know Html, css, javascript and php plus I have a web server that I run which could e of some help i it requires a database.

Thanks once again. Owen

Comment: You'll need to be more specific on what you need help with. There's lots of solutions already out there (some free, other paid), are you trying to build one from scratch? Every solution will be different, and you may need to do more research to find out what will work best for you.

Comment: @SunnyPatel has said it nicely.

Comment: i am trying to build one from scratch